# How do I implement networklayer where it requires chain requests first request for token and then API always?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, alamofire

I am implementing a network layer using Alamofire. 
I have requirement of requesting a token for all the APIs if it gets succeeded then need to do Actual API request. Can Some one suggest how to implement network layer with chain requests and all requests should go to background thread by default irrespective of the thread it called from.

Comment: Show what you've tried so far?

Comment: The question is too broad to answer, please provide further details like what was your approach, where you failed? what is the structure of the layer?

Comment: I did not fail i thought of using Alamofire and Promises for chaining. May be my question limited to how can I achieve this using only Alamofire.